# MIxins not working in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have code:

main.js

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSession from 'vue-session'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

import AuthHelper from './utils/AuthHelper'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(VueSession)

Vue.mixin(AuthHelper)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

AuthHelper.js

```
export default {
  methods: {
    isLogged () {
      if (!this.$session.exists()) {
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'Login'
        })
      }
    },
    logout: () => {
      this.$session.destroy()
      this.$router.push({
        name: 'Login'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

And my problem is that I can't use method isLogged() in component. Every time I have error that this.isLogged() is not a function.

I am confused, because I do the same as documentation.

@edit
In component I using:

```
export default {
  name: 'Profil',
  data () {
    return {
      user: this.$session.get('user'),
      oldpass: '',
      newpass: '',
      newpassrepeat: '',
      error: [],
      error2: []
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.isLogged()
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you're using the mixin in the `App` component. Can you update the question to show that usage?

Comment: One visible error; never use arrow functions to define methods in Vue.

Comment: I edited question how i using it in component.

Comment: That should work: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/m78vqw4qzp). Seems like an important detail is missing.

Comment: Yea... Its working, but I am stupid and used bad route. Its reason that mixins doesn't working.

Comment: so what was the issue?